# Создание в конфиге ссылки на переменную

Tags: php, json, config

мне нужно сделать вот так: 
Есть конфиг

```
"test": {
    "x": "120",
    "y": "50",
    "size": "20",
    "color": "#FFAA00",
    "text": "Цена {$values}"
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы когда я вызывал`$config['test'][text]`, выводило: Цена ... (значение переменной)

Comment: Для этого есть функция `json_decode` - второй параметр функции если поставить в `true` будет вам массив.

Comment: лол, я про то что мне нужно выводить значение переменной $values

Answer (score 0):

> *нужно выводить значение переменной $values*

Используйте оператор конкатенации *(точка)*:

```
$values = '123';

$json = '{"test": {
    "x": "120",
    "y": "50",
    "size": "20",
    "color": "#FFAA00",
    "text": "Цена ' . $values . '"
}}';

$config = json_decode($json, true);

echo $config['test']['text']; // Цена 123
```

Comment: У меня не работает, вот что выводит `Цена ' . $valute . '`

Comment: @I.Ageyev копируйте код из моего примера целиком, и последовательно его изменяйте под свои нужды.